# Deallocated ViewController inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The structure of my code is this:

`UITableViewController` (with one or more)-> Custom `UITableviewCell` (add the view of)-> `UIViewController`

Now, to notify an action on the `UIViewController` to the `UITableViewController` I have a protocol that follow the inverse flow explained before, but, when I do some action on `UIViewController`, app crashes because I'm trying to access to a deallocated instance...

I avoid the crash on IBAction on `UIViewController` in a dirty way: setting a property in the `UIViewController` as `self`

How can I solved this leak? This is my code:

UITableViewController:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GameTableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellId];
    [cell configureWithGame: currentGame];

    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

Custom TableViewCell:

```
-(void)configureWithGame:(Game *)game
{
    outcomeController = [[OutcomeViewController alloc] initWithGame:game];
    outcomeController.delegate = self;

    activeGame = game;

    //Adapting outcomeView
    CGRect frame = outcomeController.view.frame;
    frame.size = self.outcomeView.frame.size;
    outcomeController.view.frame = frame;
    [[self.outcomeView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [self.outcomeView addSubview:outcomeController.view];
}
```

The OutcomeViewController has a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) id forceRetain;` and it sets in `-(void)viewDidLoad` in this way:

```
self.forceRetain = self;
```

This causes some leaks and I want to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting `outcomeController` property to `strong`in your cell code.

Moreover, with the code you posted, the `OutcomeViewController` will be allocated every time you scroll the `UITableView`. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: Yes, it's what I want. It is yet strong referenced in cell code

Comment: try to insert the add 'addChildViewController:' inside 'configureWithGame'